# What is order of general linear group GL(3,Zp)?

Tags: group-theory

I have tried for $GL(2,\mathbb{Z}_p)$ its $= (p^2-1)(p^2-p)$
Since as number of ways in which first row can be filled is $p^2-1$ by omitting the way in which all entries r zero and second row can be filled in $p^2-p$ ways by omitting the  ways in which d entries are multiples of first row.
I have also  tried for for $GL(3,\mathbb{Z}_p)$ its found as $=(p^3-1)(p^3-p)(p^3-2p)$.
Is it right?

Comment: The last factor is $p^3-p^2$, since the span of the first two columns (they span a two-dimensional space) is not allowed.

Comment: The size of the group $GL(n,q)$ is $(q^n-1)(q^n-q)\cdots (q^n-q^{n-1})$, where $n$ and $q$ are positive integers.